# Will videos/slides from the UDS be available?

Tags: video, uds

Will videos/slides from the UDS be available on the internet and if so where?

I've been searching for them but all I could find was some session logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Videos go to the Youtube Channel:

- http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers

They get posted originally to

- http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/

and then distributed to YouTube and archive.org. The AV team typically gets the videos up a day or so after the session has happened, so the UDS videos will be uploaded as they are finished.

Audio recordings of each session are [available here](http://mirrors.tumbleweed.org.za/uds-o/).